# Access props inside curly brace in React JS

Tags: reactjs, jsx

How does one access a value from props `props.id` inside a controlled input?

What I want to achieve.

```
<input
  name="lname"
  value={pax.adult1.lname} // This gets/displays input on state change
  onChange={handleChange}
  type="text"
  placeholder="Last name"
  className="form-control"
/>;
```

What I have tried:

```
<input
  name="lname"
  value={pax.adult`${props.id}`.lname} // This throws an error
  onChange={handleChange}
  type="text"
  placeholder="Last name"
  className="form-control"
/>;
```

I have also tried the following

```
value={pax.adult + props.id + `.lname`} // NaN.lname
```

And

```
value={`pax.adult${props.id}.lname`} // This displays the right value "pax.adult1.lname" but as a string
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try this: `value={pax['adult'+ props.id].lname}`

Comment: @Ramesh it shows syntax error.

Comment: I misunderstood your issue I've edited try now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like that:

```
<input
  name="lname"
  value={pax[`adult${props.id}`].lname}
  onChange={handleChange}
  type="text"
  placeholder="Last name"
  className="form-control"
/>;
```

Answer (score 1):

The code between the `{` `}` is just normal JS. So to access a property in an object using a variable in JS, you use square brackets and pass a string, list so: `obj["aString"]`.

In your case, it would be:

```
pax["adult" + props.id].lname
```

or, to make it better looking:

```
pax[`adult${props.id}`].lname
```